# How do I select a value from drop down in selenium webdriver using python?

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How do I select a value from drop down in selenium webdriver using python?

I am unable to access the drop down elements.elements are in form of labels.

Expected is i want to pick a value from drop down. and value don't have any id. when i try to right click on my elements in drop down,drop down gets closed.

Screen shot when drop down is opened:

[image: Screen shot when drop down is opened]

Image when down is closed:

[image: Image when down is closed]

Find the code to click the drop down

```
lead_quality_dropdownclick = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vs"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div')
lead_quality_dropdownclick.click()
print("Lead quality drop down is opened")
```

Comment: Can you share the code you have tried so far?

Comment: Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Comment: Xpath you are using is absolute and fragile, you should go for relative xpath.

Answer (score 0):

You can ask Selenium to click on the arrow behind the drop down menu and than let it search for your content.

To click, you can use:

```
      from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait  # Allows to wait for a page to load
      from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC  # Specify what you are looking for on a specific page

      time_out = 20 #wait till the site is loaded before you click
      try:
         WebDriverWait(driver,
              time_out).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, 'put the path here'))).click()
```

The XPath can be found by a right click on the code that leads to the arrow and copy the XPath.

Comment: hi sir.Thank you for your reply. While the issue is am not able to right click the drop down. If i click them drop down vanishes or closes. I wrote code till clicking the drop down.Find the code below:                                                                                                   lead_quality_dropdownclick = driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="vs"]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[1]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div')
lead_quality_dropdownclick.click()
print("Lead quality drop down is opened")

Comment: Does it print; ‘lead quality drop down is opened?’ Otherwise it might be that you have to enter a time-out (to wait) or a different path. If this does not work, can you update your question with the complete code and a link to the site? Otherwise I’m not able to test this and help you in finding the answer.

Comment: Have you tried using the arrow down key? You could press arrow down key a number of times till you get to the item, after clicking on the arrow button. 

Also, what I do when all things fail is to write a javascript code that does what I want, and then run it with `driver.execute_script()`

Comment: Hi Yes print is working for me. but i don't know how to pick value from drop down as its too dynamic.

Comment: check this [site](https://www.guru99.com/select-option-dropdown-selenium-webdriver.html) for the drop down list values. or this [StackOverFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49058624/selenium-selecting-an-item-from-dropdown-list-if-the-values-are-inside-table) question. or follow this [site's](http://elementalselenium.com/tips/5-select-from-a-dropdown) instructions